# Exclude from * in command line

Tags: command-line, bash, rm

There are plenty of situations where the use of a `*` is virtually inevitable - e.g. `rm -rf *` in a folder that holds thousands of subfolders and files.

But what if you want to exclude just one or two files or folders from the `rm` command? I've googled my way around and only found quite complicated solutions like `find . -depth -not \( -name 'one' -o -name 'two' \
-o -name 'three' \) -exec rm {} \;` as stated [here](http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-de/2004-08/msg01219.html).

Is there a possibility to do this in an easier way - without that detour to `find`?
E.g. `rm -rf --exclude='one' --exclude='two' --exclude='three' *` like in rsync or just `rm -rf -e 'one','two','three' *`?

Maybe even a general possibility to exclude things from `*` (so other commands like `cp`, `mv`, ... don't have to implement their own)? Something like `*{'one','two','three'}` or so?

Comment: If you want to keep only one or two files then the simplest and easiest way would be to move those files to another location, wipe all remaining files and move the ones you kept back. If you want to keep a lot more files I would use `find` with the `--delete` option (no need to execute `rm` for each file. That is needless overhead).

Comment: That would be a possibility, but it is nearly as elaborate as the one I mentioned. I know I could combine the commands to something like `mv -t /tmp one two three && rm -rf * && mv -t . /tmp/one /tmp/two /tmp/three`, but I would prefer a solution giving the possibility to explicitely exclude something from `*`. There will surely be situations where moving or copying the files to another destination won't be an option.

Comment: It is, which is why I did not post it as an answer. Merely as a less complex way of doing things (three very simple commands vs one somewhat more complex ones). I hate complexity in combination with rm.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Bash there is a shell option called `extglob` that is [deactivated by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191796/2656118) to keep compatibility with standard shell syntax. [Extglob](http://en.chys.info/2009/02/extglob/) complements the syntax by additional operators like `!()`, `?()`, `@()` and some more.

To switch `extglob` on, type `shopt -s extglob`. To keep it switched on for the current user type `echo 'shopt -s extglob' >> ~/.bashrc`.

For the rm example: With `extglob` you can use

```
rm -rf !(one|two|three)
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but I also don't want to switch that on and off everytime I get into a situation like the described one.

Comment: @David: you could put the `shopt` thing into your `~/.bashrc`, it cannot hurt.

Comment: If I get it right, the extglob option does not change the effect of `*` at all, but instead adds similar indicators (like the `!`) that have additional functions?

In that case it would be a lovely solution.

Comment: @David: Exactly.

Comment: Why the actual hell is this thing not enabled by default, then? >:O

Comment: @David *To keep compatibility with standard shell syntax*.  There are likely other situations where behaviour may change.

Comment: This is by the way exactly what I was looking for. 8)

Answer (score 4):

I've built [except](https://github.com/helpermethod/except) exactly for that (sry that I wasn't able to add documentation yet).

I you have a folder like the following:

```
$ ls
a b c d
```

Typing `except b d` will give you `a` and `c`

```
$ except b d
ac
```

Now you can pipe that to `rm`.

```
except b d | xargs -0 rm
```

This may be hard to remember, so why not just build a script on top of except, called
`rm-except`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

except "$@" | xargs -0 rm
```

Similarly easy is `ls-except`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

except "$@" | xargs -0 ls
```

Comment: This is nice, but not really needed when you know about extglob - http://askubuntu.com/a/329233/138369

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to extglob (though that is a very good answer and everyone should have `shopt -s extglob globstar` in their .bashrc), you can use the [$GLOBIGNORE global variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globignore). Let's say you want to get every file except 'foo.txt' and 'bar baz.txt':

```
GLOBIGNORE=foo.txt:'bar baz.txt'
```

...however, this will turn the shell option `dotglob` on, which means that `*` will match files beginning with a dot (which are normally hidden). So you actually need two commands:

```
GLOBIGNORE=foo.txt:'bar baz.txt'
shopt -u dotglob
```

Since this is a global variable, it will affect every glob you use until $GLOBSTAR is unset either by logging out or with

```
GLOBIGNORE=
```

It will also only work on the literal strings passed to the variable. You can see what I mean by setting $GLOBIGNORE and looking at the difference between these commands:

```
printf '%s\n' *
printf '%s\n' ./*
```