# What does `!` symbol mean in Ubuntu

Tags: find

I've looked all over, and I can't find out what `!` means in Ubuntu, I see it all over. eg:

```
find -f -d !(.txt)
```

Comment: The exclamation point `!` means different things in different contexts - sometimes negation, sometimes history expansion. The particular context in your question is unclear (it doesn't seem to be a valid command).

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/understanding-the-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Comment: That's a fascinating link @AndroidDev why not copy and paste contents into answer here?

Comment: `!` has many meanings in different places. Listing all of them would be too broad. The command you have entered is not a valid find command, so ask about a valid command so that we can make sense of it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done :)

Answer (score 3):

From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3748

> `!` is a feature that originally appeared in the C shell, back in the
>   days before you could count on terminals to have arrow keys.  It's
>   especially useful if you add the current command number to the prompt
>   (`PS1="\!$ "`) so you can quickly look at your screen to get numbers
>   for past commands.
>
> Now that you can use arrow keys and things like <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> to
>   search the command history, I don't see much use for the feature.
>
> One variant of it you might still find useful is `!!`, which
>   re-executes the previous command. On its own, I don't find
>   <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> any faster than just
>   <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it can be helpful when
>   combined into a larger command.
>
> **Example:** A common [pilot error](http://foldoc.org/pilot+error) on [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) based systems is to forget the `sudo`
>   prefix on a command that requires extra privileges. A novice retypes
>   the whole command. The diligent student edits the command from the
>   shell's command history. The enlightened one types `sudo !!`.
>
> Bash lets you disable `!` processing in the shell with `set +o
>   histexpand` or `set +H`. You can disable it in Zsh with `set -K`.

Comment: This particular use of `!` though, is more like extended globbing: http://askubuntu.com/a/329233/158442

Answer (score 2):

Outside its use in shell history expansion covered in [Android Dev's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/903061/178692), the most common use is to express negation or set complementation. For example, in simple shell globs

```
ls [!a-c]*
```

lists files **except those** starting with a character in the range `a-c`. You may also see this written with a caret in place of the exclamation point `[^a-c]` (borrowed from regular expression syntax) although the latter form is not POSIX compliant.

Bash extends the notion of complementation to whole patterns in its [extended shell globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) so that for example

```
ls !(*.txt)
```

would list all files excluding those ending in a `.txt` extension.

Some individual commands also independently use `!` in the sense of negation or logical complementation - for example

```
find ! -name '*.txt'
```

although GNU `find` at least also supports the longer form `-not` in this context (although again this is not POSIX compliant).

Your example seems to confuse these last two usages - it looks like an extended shell glob, but occurs as part of a `find` command where such a shell expansion would not be valid<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> an extended shell glob could however be used to construct a list of *directories* for `find` to search - something like `find !(foo*)/ -name '*.bar'` for example